# Github organization invitation

Tags: github

In github a organization send me an invite to join them by mistake i have blocked that organization to send me any future invite. I want to change this and allow the organization to send me invite to join them

Resolution to unblock the organisation to send me future invites.

Comment: Is there no "unblock" button or menu entry on the org page?

Comment: An org should not be that different from a regular user: https://docs.github.com/en/communities/maintaining-your-safety-on-github/unblocking-a-user-from-your-personal-account